# Why is a Node/Jest runtime syntax error thrown when performing a non-declarative destructing assignment to variable(s) with global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, es6-modules

Performing a destructuring assignment on global variables anywhere in an ES6 module results in the following error being thrown when running a Jest test configured with the '--experimental-vm-modules' CLI option in VSCode:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
>
>   at Runtime.loadEsmModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:551:22)
> ```

Adding the following line after initial declaration, or within function scope results in the error.

> `[globalOne, globalTwo] = ["", ""];`

The code executes without issue in the browser (Chrome/Safari/Firefox).

Separately, are there any Node or Jest CLI configs that would help trace line numbers that throw this type of parsing error? Tracking down the culprit was a bit too manual.

Edit:

example_module.js

```
var globalOne, globalTwo;
[globalOne, globalTwo] = ["", ""];
```

example_module.test.js

```
import * as example_module from './example_module.js';
```

Visual Studio Code | .vscode/launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug Example",
        "type": "node",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/PROJECT/",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--experimental-vm-modules",
            "--inspect-brk",
            "${workspaceRoot}/PROJECT/node_modules/.bin/jest",
            "--runInBand",
            "--testPathPattern",
            "example_module.test.js"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "port": 9229
    }
]
}
```

Both example_module.js and example_module.test.js in '${workspaceRoot}/PROJECT/'

Comment: Post the surrounding code.

Comment: All I get from that is `Uncaught ReferenceError: globalOne is not defined`.

Comment: The code context I've added in the edit above should go on to throw `Your test suite must contain at least one test.`, but instead encounters the assignment error.